# Git doesn't push directory changes

Tags: git, directory

If I make changes to the directories on my development server (e.g. removing a directory, adding a directory, moving files to other directories), those seem to be things it doesn't push to the main server.
How can I make it do that anyway? How can I make sure everything stays synchronized?

Comment: are the directories empty? are they under source control?

Comment: Hi J. Fr., and welcome to Stack Overflow.  For people to be able to help, I think you'll need to add more details to your question - for example, are you moving the files between directories with `git mv` or just renaming?  Are you pushing to a bare repository or one with a working tree?  What does `git status` show before you push?  Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use `git push` to publish commits and `git pull` to get the latest tree from the remote origin. Git is a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Version_Control_System) with a different workflow as compared to centralized version control systems. [See here for an introduction on distributed workflows](http://book.git-scm.com/3_distributed_workflows.html).